# Получение информации об атрибутах

Tags: c++, clang, libclang

Можно ли с помощью libclang получить атрибуты члена класса?

Пример кода:

```
class User
{
/* code */
private:
    [[attr_a]]
    const std::string m_username;
    __attribute__((attr_b))
    const std::string m_password;
};
```

При обходе AST, дойдя до элемента соответствующего `m_username`, я бы хотел получить информацию об атрибуте `attr_a` из его [курсора](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/structCXCursor.html).

На данный момент я не нашел ничего подходящего в документации по [libclang API](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX.html), за исключением функции, которая просто возвращает признак наличия/отсутствия атрибутов у элемента данного курсора: [clang_Cursor_hasAttrs](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX__CURSOR__MANIP.html#ga2bcf84ce3d5158457451e051afbdc8dd) (если в документации идет речь о *тех* курсорах, конечно).

**UPD.:** на enSO нашел [дополнительную информацию](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19653767/inspecting-generalized-attributes-with-libclang) - если использовать следующую форму:

```
__attribute__((annotate("...")))
```

, то `clang_Cursor_hasAttrs()` вернет `true`. Для вышеупомянутых форм записи это не работало.